# MongoDB unwind aggregation query giving unexpected results

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

To see which documents in a users collection has links to a specific user I use the following aggregation query:

```
db.getCollection("users").aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        $or: [
            {_id: ObjectId("5b63133c45a56952c9430776")},
            {_id: ObjectId("5b69caec45a56952c8010bdb")},
            {_id: ObjectId("5bb49ece45a5696eb624c4f4")}
        ]    
    }
},

{
    $unwind: {path: "$network"}
},

{
    $project: {_id:1,network:1}
},

{
    $match: 
        {"network.id": "5c958c7745a5691cff06f252"}
}

])
```

which gives the following result showing that only one of the three users are matched:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b69caec45a56952c8010bdb"),
    "network" : {
        "id" : "5c958c7745a5691cff06f252",
        "status" : "connected",
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2019-06-27T00:58:45.501Z")
    }
}
```

But if I query the three users individually, like for example the first one:

```
db.getCollection("users").find({_id:ObjectId("5b63133c45a56952c9430776")}, {network:1});
```

A network item is found that does not show up in the aggregation query (see item 113):

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b63133c45a56952c9430776"),
    "network" : {
        "0" : {
            "id" : "5b61b7c845a56960683cc53c",
            "status" : "connected",
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2019-06-26T03:48:38.293Z")
        },
        "1" : {
            "id" : "5bc7ee7745a56931124e50de",
            "status" : "sent"
        },

        ...

        "113" : {
            "id" : "5c958c7745a5691cff06f252",
            "status" : "connected",
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2019-06-28T07:19:34.463Z")
        },

        ...

    }
}
```

Is my aggregation query wrong or is this a bug in the aggregation framework?

MongoDB version 3.6.6

Comment: Really strange, are you sure your aggregate is only returning one value? I made a Fiddle (https://mongoplayground.net/p/5hHOryuS7ZX)  to test your query and it's getting more than one user, though I did not test with a bigger network array

Comment: Positive. It only returns one value. Thanks for the effort with the fiddle and the measure of confirmation this brings, @MatheusHatje

Comment: Because you made `$unwind` to the `network` array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh dear. The problem was that the network element format was inconsistent. On some documents the network element could be unwound, because it was an array:

```
"network": [
      {
        "id": "5c958c7745a5691cff06f252",
        "status": "connected"
      },
      {
        "id": "5bc7ee7745a56931124e50de",
        "status": "sent"
      }
    ]
```

On others, the $unwind directive did nothing, because the format was a keyed object:

```
"network" : {
        "0" : {
            "id" : "5b61b7c845a56960683cc53c",
            "status" : "connected",
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2019-06-26T03:48:38.293Z")
        },
        "1" : {
            "id" : "5bc7ee7745a56931124e50de",
            "status" : "sent"
        }
     }
```

So, after normailsing the format across the collection, everything worked as expected. :facepalm: